# Grep the same symbol

Tags: bash, awk, grep

This is my df -h output

```
 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           98G   82G   17G  83% /
none             98G   82G   17G  83% /dev
none             98G   82G   17G  83% /run
none             98G   82G   17G  83% /run/lock
none             98G   82G   17G  83% /run/shm
none             98G   82G   17G  83% /run/user
tmpfs            98G   82G   17G  83% /sys/fs/cgroup
C:\              98G   82G   17G  83% /mnt/c
```

and i want to view only the

```
rootfs           98G   82G   17G  83% /
C:\              98G   82G   17G  83% /mnt/c
```

how to do that? C:\ may be different, but /mnt/c mountpoint stays the same

how to do that using grep? or other linux tools
thanks for the help!

Comment: note you can say `df -h /` to get just the info from `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have not posted on which O.S you are in, so I am going with your shown sample output where output of `df` comes in single lines NOT like in 2 lines as RHEL 6 it was.

```
df -h | awk '$NF=="/mnt/c" || $NF=="/"'
```

OR in case you are on Linux 6 then you could use `df -hP` to get df output in a single like so above will become like:

```
df -hP | awk '$NF=="/mnt/c" || $NF=="/"'
```

Answer (score 4):

> C:\ may be different, but /mnt/c mountpoint stays the same

Just:

```
df -h / /mnt/c
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with simply doing a

```
df -h|grep -E '(^rootfs|/mnt/c)'
```

?